# Visual Studio System.OutOfMemoryException

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio

I have strange problem.

In some moment when i tried to run my c# asp.net web pages app my visual studio has been crashed with message System.OutOfMemoryException. I tried to place breakpoints , but it happens before running of the app. I tried to open another asp.net mvc project and have same problem.

Visual Studio Comunity 2017  15.8.1, Intel Core i5, 8gb Ram - only 53% is used.
First project is asp.net web pages Net.4.5, second is Asp.net MVC .Net.4.6.

Please help to understand where is problem:

Stack Trace:

```
System.OutOfMemoryException
[OutOfMemoryException:  "System.OutOfMemoryException".]
   System.Web.Compilation.MultiTargetingUtil.InitializeKnownAndLatestFrameworkNames() +0
   System.Web.Compilation.MultiTargetingUtil.EnsureFrameworkNamesInitialized() +144
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.Initialize() +347
   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.InitializeBuildManager() +323
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.HostingInit(HostingEnvironmentFlags hostingFlags, PolicyLevel policyLevel, Exception appDomainCreationException) +662

[HttpException (0x80004005): "System.OutOfMemoryException".]
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.FirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +523
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.EnsureFirstRequestInit(HttpContext context) +107
   System.Web.HttpRuntime.ProcessRequestNotificationPrivate(IIS7WorkerRequest wr, HttpContext context) +688
```

Comment: Guessing your "System" is "OutOfMemory", thus raising a self-explanatory "Exception"? :)

Comment: It would be useful (for anyone that might be able to help you) if you can be more specific about the version of Visual Studio (2015? 2017?) And also the specific update version you're running as well from Help -> About Microsoft Visual Studio. For example, I'm running *Visual Studio 2017 Community, version 15.8.6* - the issue you're encountering might be a known issue for a specific version

Comment: Also don't forget to add your machine details.

Comment: The amount of RAM you have installed is irrelevant. The amount of **available** RAM is what counts.

Comment: See debug diag, it could help to understand

Comment: Please be a little bit more specific about that "another asp.net mvc project". Can you create and run a new clean MVC project? And which framework: 4.x or Core 2.x   ?

Comment: @Reniuz added details

Comment: @Stijn: not even that. The amount of memory to be allocated and the amount of available virtual memory is needed. You can easily crash a 32 bit application with `var b=new byte[4294967295];`. No matter how much RAM is free, it will cause OOM.

Comment: @АндрейГолубцов Visual Studio crashes or your app crashes?

Comment: @Stijn - or as Raymond Chen put it - [It's the address space, stupid](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20130628-00/?p=3963)

Comment: Based on where those errors are coming from, it might be some deeply misconfigured configuration file. Are you able to reproduce this with just an empty project? If not, if you replace its `web.config` with your current one, does that reproduce the issue?

Comment: @ThomasWeller app crashed